# Reinsertar registro después de hacer softdelete

Tags: laravel-5

Tengo un modelo Role, que tiene id y role como atributos y realizo el softdelete.

Ahora si yo quiero ingresar el mismo role que hice el softdelete, tengo problemas porque me dice que ya existe y no se como hacer el restore.

Donde creo un nuevo role:

```
    public function store(NewRoleRequest $request) {         
        $request['role'] = strtoupper($request->input('role'));

        $this->roleRepo->create($request->all());

        return redirect()->route('role.create')->with('create-success', 'Role agregado correctamente.');      
    }
```

y NewRoleRequest tiene:

```
 public function rules() {
    return [
        'role' => 'required|unique:role,role|alpha'
    ];
}
```

No se como hacer que al momento de saber que ya existe este registro hacer  el:

```
$role->restore();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si quieres reinsertarlo con el mismo ID, debes eliminarlo completamente. (No olvidar de las llaves foráneas si usas una BD relacional).

Si quieres restaurarlo, debes utilizar Eloquent:

```
Role::withTrashed()->find($role_id)->restore();
```

ó

```
$role = App\Role::onlyTrashed()
            ->where('role_id', $id)
            ->get();
$role->restore();
```